# How to set focus to specific textboxes under different conditions in C#.net webforms?

Tags: c#, webforms, textbox, focus

I have four textboxes grouped to two:

- txtbox_date_start
- txtbox_date_end
- txtbox_value_start
- txtbox_value_end

[image]

All these four textboxes have AutoPostBack = true.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //copy value of txtbox_date_start to txtbox_date_end
    if ((txtbox_date_start.Text != "") && (txtbox_date_end.Text == ""))
    {
        txtbox_date_end.Text = txtbox_date_start.Text;

        // How?
        // if txtbox_date_start was focused, then set focus to txtbox_date_end
    }

    //copy value of txtbox_value_start to txtbox_value_end
    if ((txtbox_value_start.Text != "") && (txtbox_value_end.Text == ""))
    {
        txtbox_value_end.Text = txtbox_value_start.Text;

        // How?
        //if txtbox_value_start was focused, then set focus to txtbox_value_end
    }
}
```

My original pseucode is like this:

```
if txtbox_date_start is not empty and is focused,

--> then when press tab,

----> txtbox_date_end will be = to txtbox_date_start

------> and txtbox_date_end will be focused
```

same purpose for txtbox_value_start & txtbox_value_end.

I also tried to use

```
if ( txtbox_date_start.Focused == true)
```

but the Focuse() cannot be used in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use string.Empty rather than "".

I would do something along the lines of the following and focus based on the input:

```
//copy value of txtbox_date_start to txtbox_date_end
var startDate = txtbox_date_start.Text;
var endDate = txtbox_date_end.Text;

if ((startDate != string.Empty) && (endDate.Text == string.Empty))
{
    txtbox_date_end.Text = startDate;

    // How?
    // if txtbox_date_start was focused, then set focus to txtbox_date_end
    if(startDate != string.Empty && endDate == string.Empty){
        txtbox_date_end.Focus();
    }
    else if(endDate != string.Empty && startDate == string.Empty){
        txtbox_start_end.Focus();
    }
}
```